# How to open a file using _TCHAR* as a file name? c/c++

Tags: c++, c, file, tchar

My main has the following signature:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

I would like to preform the following:

```
FILE *inputFilePtr;
inputFilePtr = fopen(argv[2], "_r");
```

But there is a type mismatch. How should I do it?
Should I use:

```
inputFilePtr = _tfopen(argv[2], ??????);
```

Thanks!

Comment: The tchar.h header is non-standard and archaic.  There's no point in using it anymore, there are no non-Unicode versions of Windows left.  Use the wide versions today, _wfopen() and the L prefix on string literals.

Comment: ... and realise that `_wfopen` is non-standard, too.

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
_tfopen(argv[2], TEXT("r"));
```

Do not use:

```
_tfopen(argv[2], L"r");
```

The second one will give compilation error if the macro `UNICODE` is not defined, that is, when `TCHAR` is just `char`, not `wchar_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Use    `_tfopen(argv[2], TEXT("r"));`

or `_tfopen(argv[2], L"r");` if TCHAR is WCHAR.

Comment: Second one is not so correct. What if `TCHAR` is just `char`? `L"r"` always makes `wchar_t`, as far as I know!

Comment: You Are right @Nawaz, but in most cases TCHAR is WCHAR and this code will work. Otherwise it will give compile error and will be corrected easily.

Comment: @Mihran: As I said, what if `TCHAR` is `char`? Your code will fail!

Comment: @Mihran: Yes. That is what I'm saying : the second one is not correct!

Comment: Consistency is important, use _wfopen() instead of relying on compiler errors.  It is not you that gets it wrong, it is somebody else that will be flummoxed about you writing the code this way.

Comment: Don't be so pedantic @Nawaz ))) I changed it to be more clear.

Comment: @Mihran: Pedanticism has nothing to do with it. You should write your code so that it functions in both cases.